# Calculating $\sum_{X,Y\subseteq\Omega}P(X\cup Y)-P(X\cap Y)$ if $P$ is the uniform probability distribution in $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$?

Tags: probability

Let $P$ be the uniform probability distribution on $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. I need to calculate

$$\sum_{X,Y\subseteq\Omega}P(X\cup Y)-P(X\cap Y)$$

but I don't know how to follow from there without getting an inexact answer using inequalities. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More generaly let $\Omega=\lbrace 1 , \dots , n \rbrace$ for some $n$. Observe that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{X,Y} \left( \mathbb P(X\cup Y) - \mathbb P(X\cap Y)\right) &= \sum_{X,Y} \left(\mathbb P(X\setminus Y) + \mathbb P(Y\setminus X)\right)\\
&= 2 \sum_{X,Y} \mathbb P (X\setminus Y)\\
&=2 \sum_{A\subseteq \Omega} \mathbb P (A) \sum_{X\setminus Y = A} 1\\
&=2\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} (n-k)\sum_{X\setminus Y = \lbrace 1 ,\dots , k \rbrace} 1\\
&=2 \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}(n-k)\sum_{Y\subseteq \lbrace k+1,\dots , n\rbrace}\sum_{X = \lbrace 1 ,\dots , k \rbrace\cup Y} 1\\
&= 2\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}(n-k)\sum_{Y\subseteq \lbrace k+1,\dots , n\rbrace} 1\\
&=2\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}(n-k) 2^{n-k}\\
&=4 n 3^{n-1}
\end{align*}

Going from the line with $A$ to the line with $k$ is just observing that if $|A|=k$, then $\mathbb P(A) = n-k$ and that you can rearange a set of $k$ elements in  $n\choose k$ ways.

The last equality is the same as $\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} k 2^{k}=2\times 3^{n-1} n$ and can be proven using generating functions as
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} k p^{k} &= p\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} k p^{k-1} \\
&=p\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} \cdot\frac{d}{dp}\left[p^{k}\right]\\
&=p \cdot\frac{d}{dp}\left[\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} p^{k}\right]\\
&=p \cdot\frac{d}{dp} \left[(p+1)^n\right]\\
&=n p(p+1)^{n-1}
\end{align*}

Comment: In step 2 you assumed $P(X-Y)=P(Y-X)$.

Comment: @Garmekain no I assumed that $\sum_{X,Y} P(X\setminus Y) = \sum_{X,Y} P(Y\setminus X)$, just by relabeling